# Issue with ASP.NET MVC 5 and Bootstrap 5 Theme

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-5

I dont' know why the code generated by VS2022 for MVC 5 project has css class name different from that one used in bootstrap theme.

For validation error, for example, asp.net generate ".field-validation-error" class but this is not present in bootstrap file. While it has ".invalid-feedback" class.

What am I missing?

This is what I've done:

- downloaded a bootstrap 5 .css theme file (superhero.css)
- added it to the Content folder
- changed the BundleConfig.cs with this code

`bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include( "~/Content/superhero.css","~/Content/site.css"));`